# How can I reload just the collection view cells?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionViewController with a UICollectionReusableView in the header section. I have a UISegmentedControl within the header that reloads the data in the collection view cells. However, I also have a button that shows the state of the relationship with users, but when I change the segments, the button's title is changed to it's default state. How can I only reload the collection view cells without reloading the data in the header?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to reload all the visible cells, since that makes perfect sense:

```
collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems())
```

This will reload the visible cells.

Comment: Am I supposed to state the indecis within the .indexPathsForVisibleItems()?

Comment: @user4513956 Huh? You don't need index paths if that's what you are talking about. You get them from that method.

Comment: I actually have a function that queries data when the segments are changed. So I'm reloading the collection view in there with self.collectionView!.reloadData(). I replaced it with your code and it doesn't work....

Comment: @user4513956 does it not work as in a compiler error, it doesn't reload anything, or it reloads the header also?

Comment: It reloads the header also, and I don't want it to do that

Comment: Actually if I use your code, it doesn't reload at all haha

Comment: @user4513956 Ah okay, try adding `print(collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems())` before it and tell me what it prints in the console.

Comment: It returns nil... more specifically, it's empty --> [ ]. By the way nice app haha